# macOS root password & malware?

Tags: macos, security, malware

I entered my macOS admin details (root password) into an application I think was malicious. Suspicious, I checked the keychain and my tokens had modified passwords.

What else could have this software done? Where would I look? More importantly what can I do to check / protect myself?

I deleted all keychain entries and changed all passwords...

Comment: What was the app? Why was it asking for admin authentication?

Comment: Welcome on Stack Exchange. Could you add in your original question: - the version of MacOS you are running, - if the application which asked your password is still installed on your Mac.

Comment: @benwiggy : even the highest quality application don’t explain us why they are asking our password. This is a pretty old abuse of trust which is easily mimicked by malware.

Answer (score 1):

You can get and run Malwarebytes. This supposedly finds any malware on your Mac. If that finds nothing I'd look for a virus checker with a free trial period and run it as a secondary test. [Here is a link](https://www.macworld.com/article/3263722/best-antivirus-for-mac.html) to a review of Mac virus checkers. [Malwarebytes can be found at this link](https://www.malwarebytes.com/mac/).